# Find the countries with a GDP greater than a group of countries

Tags: sql

I'm attempting question 5 of SQLZoo's [SELECT within SELECT tutorial](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial)

> Which countries have a GDP greater than any country in Europe? [Give the name only.]

This is my solution, which is incorrect but I don't understand why.

```
SELECT name  
  FROM world  
 WHERE gdp > ALL (SELECT gdp FROM world WHERE continent ='Europe')
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: what's wrong? I'm getting a happy face using your answer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssdan.jpg

Comment: It keeps coming up for me as "Too few rows"

Comment: OK, I used firefox and it told me my answer was correct... but with chrome it didnt. -_-

http://imgur.com/4H3rbML

Answer (score 11):

```
select name, gdp 
from world x 
where gdp > all (select gdp from world y where continent = "Europe" and gdp > 0)
```

you were missing a NULL value check because in case of null value unknown result will be fetched, see ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html

world table might have null values for some European countries when you tested your query therefore it is good to put a check to avoid null values.

Comment: can I write `gdp <> NULL` instead of `gdp > 0`?

Comment: or simply ```SELECT name FROM world
 WHERE gdp > ALL
      (SELECT gdp FROM world
        WHERE continent='Europe' and gdp is not null)```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT name 
  FROM world 
 WHERE gdp > (SELECT MAX(gdp) FROM world WHERE continent = 'Europe')
```

Using the MAX aggregate function returns the highest GDP from the sub-query which is what you want to compare with the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from world 
 where gdp > ALL(select gdp from world 
 where continent = 'Europe' 
   and gdp is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the questions consecutively and for some reason Germany was in my mind from the previous question. So I had this in my query and got a correct answer. LOL Try it. I am using Chrome

select name from world
where gdp > ALL(
select gdp from world
where name='Germany' and population<>0)

Answer (score 0):

Since GDP has a null value so answer will be null if you compare any other value with null.

```sql
SELECT name FROM world
WHERE
GDP > ALL(SELECT COALESCE(GDP,0) FROM world WHERE continent = 'Europe');
```

In above if you pass `COALESCE(GDP,0)`, that means you are passing GDP column and if any value is Null in GDP, then COALESCE function will return '0' (user provided value).

Passing 0 as a standard value for comparison as 0 is the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
We can select maximum out of all and then apply the greater than condition

```
select name from world where gdp > (select max(gdp) from world where continent = 'Europe')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM world
WHERE gdp >(SELECT MAX(gdp) FROM world WHERE continent = 'Europe' OR gdp > NULL);
```

You only need to use the **OR** statement as some countries come with gdp = NULL and that's what make your code error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name 
from world
where gdp >= all(
    select gdp
    from world
    where 
    continent = 'Europe' and gdp is not null)
and continent <>'Europe'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT name   FROM world  WHERE  gdp>= ALL(select gdp from world where continent='europe' and gdp>=0) and continent !='europe'
```

Comment: While code only answers might solve the question, it's better to provide some explanation about the solution and why the code is better or what part of the code solves the problem. This is also more helpful for others and helps people to learn.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE GDP > ALL(SELECT GDP
FROM world
WHERE continent='Europe' and GDP>0 )

**Null value problem**